# Regex Espression for first names validation

Tags: java, regex, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application, and in my page I have an input field where the user writes his/her first name, and I would like to avoid that they type charatcters like `@`, ?,!,,$,%..etc.

In my validator I would like to use an expression which allow the biggest set of characters, for example apostrophes, accent marks and so on.

```
 @Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors)
{
    //the email must be unique
    super.validate(target, errors); 

    User user= (User) target;

    if (!user.matches("[a-zA-Z ]"))) {
        errors.rejectValue("user.name", "user.name.invalid");
    }

}
```

Does anybody can help me to add a wider validation than [a-zA-Z ] ?

Comment: What else do you want to allow? Why don't you just add it to the character range `[...]`?

Comment: because if I add character by character I have to parse the alphabet of 7-8 different languages and add those letters individually, while if I could include this particular letters in a range I would have everything for free...

Comment: @daniele use `\\p{L}` for unicode letters and `\\p{N}` for unicode numbers.

Comment: You can use a character range to remove characters, also. `[^@?!]` means "none of these characters". Also, you know that your regex is only allowing names that are one character in length?

Comment: So what, exactly, do you want to forbid/allow? "So on" isn't really helping define it...

Comment: I don't mind the length

Comment: @SabujHassan \\p{L} will include only letters excluding numbers and characters like )(*%@12 etc.?

Comment: @Robin So on: lets say only letters and spaces, by of the widest range of alphabets

Comment: There's a nice [blog post](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) about names... accents, umlauts, hyphens, even punctuation can occur in first names.

Comment: @tobias_k thanks but I do not need to allow all the alphabets in this world, just the 6/7 most common western alphabets

Comment: A name can be of any length and can contain almost any character. It's  a pointless exercise trying to restrict it without annoying some people. As a person with a double-barrelled name (with accents in it to boot), I know exactly how annoying short-sighted validation can be.

Comment: @tobias_k: I've been looking for that blog post for weeks now, thanks!

Comment: @biziclop I agee with you A name could be of any length but the field in my db has a restricted length, and also I guess that the size of the documents is also predefined, I have never seen someone at the airport with a passport of a size A4

Comment: @daniele Of course you have to set a maximum, but some websites inexplicably set a 3 character minimum. And there's the Xhosa language where `!` denotes a click consonant, there's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Vennegoor_of_Hesselink who has a space in his name and so on...

Comment: String lengths you don't have to necessarily check with the regex; you may just check that before or after, or truncate after the check (which is not so friendly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case it would be easiest to define a "blacklist" instead of a "whitelist", as you know, what you don't want to have in the string, but don't quite know, what you need tolerate.
As @AntonH suggested, you should check for

```
[^@ ?!\,$%]+
```

instead of a giant and possibly incomplete "whitelist" of characters and ranges.
This means "a string of length one or more containing none of the specified characters.

Comment: `!` is a valid character in names, it denotes a click consonant. And so is whitespace, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Vennegoor_of_Hesselink. This is a fool's errand.

Comment: Then just allow it by not defining it in the blacklist. This is easier and better readable than adding it to a whitelist.

Comment: I agree it's a better solution in principle.